# Form validating radio buttons by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using the following script:

```
 if($('.fmscr:checked').val()){
        $('.fmscr').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.fmscr').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    }else{
        $('.fmscr').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $('.fmscr').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
    }
```

On the following radio in a form:

```
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-xs-12'>
            <p>
            Were you subject to the (FMSCR's) Department of Transportation (DOT) Regulations while employed?<span class='req'> *</span>
            </p>
            <label class='radio-inline'>
                <input type='radio' class='fmscr checked' name='fmscr[]' value='1'> Yes
            </label>
            <label class='radio-inline'>
                <input type='radio' class='fmscr checked' name='fmscr[]' value='-1'> No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is an undetermined amount of radio buttons. The script above is run on submission, but it doesn't count the radio buttons until both were checked, and also only one radio button is checked. So what am I doing wrong here? I want to be able to have all radio buttons checked regardless of quantity and have them be able to validate properly. Please let me know if any further information is needed! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed have multiple groups of `radio` buttons sharing the same class selector, the following code should help:

```
$('.fmscr:checked').each(function() {
   if( this.value ) {
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't account for the previous or next values of each. Say I have Yes as the first option and No as the second option. Both radios share the `.checked` class. If Yes is selected, then success, but then it goes to the next radio, no, and it is not selected. It is not failed, even though an option is selected.

Comment: When you have radio buttons sharing the same `name` attribute, only one can be checked at a time. Can you create a jsfiddle to show what you're explaining?

Comment: And don't confuse `.checked` with `:checked` ... **they are not one and the same**. In the code you have `:checked` while in your comment above you're referring to `.checked`. Can you clarify this with an update in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Your code

```
if ($('.fmscr:checked').val())
```

...only takes into account the first found element that match the selector. See here for details: http://api.jquery.com/val/ 
I didn't understand exactly what you want to do, but you can try it like this:

```
if ($('.fmscr:checked').length > 0 )) // at least one is checked
```

Good luck!

Comment: it clearly says what I'm trying to do. I thought having all radio buttons of a similar name as a name array would allow any number of them to be checked regardless of count? Basically these buttons are part of an employment form and they have the option to add or remove employment, and when they add employment it duplicates the form via `.clone()`

Comment: Then why not use checkboxes? You cannot check multiple radio buttons from the same group.

Comment: because I only want them to be able to select either yes or no from each question not both answers

Comment: Well, as I said, you cannot select multiple radio buttons from the same group. The only solution is to give each of them different names, such as fmscr_1, fmscr_2 and so on.